# Apache remembers .htaccess induced redirect command

Tags: apache2

I wanted to redirect `localhost/~mu/` to `localhost/~mu/branches_index/` and created a `.htaccess` file with a `Redirect /~mu/ /~mu/branches_index/`. That did not work out as expected since it changed every single files, even in other folders.

Then I created an `index.php` with the simple content of:

```
<?php
header('location:branches_index/');
?>
```

The `.htaccess` file is deleted.

If I now open `localhost/~mu/`, I end up at:

```
http://localhost/~mu/branches_index/index.phpbranches_index/index.phpbranches_index/index.phpbranches_index/index.phpbranches_index/index.phpbranches_index/index.phpbranches_index/index.phpbranches_index/index.phpbranches_index/index.phpbranches_index/index.phpbranches_index/index.phpbranches_index/index.phpbranches_index/index.phpbranches_index/index.phpbranches_index/index.phpbranches_index/index.phpbranches_index/index.phpbranches_index/index.phpbranches_index/index.php
```

If I open `localhost/~mu/index.php`, I end up at `localhost/~mu/branches_index/`.

Rebooting did not help and I am pretty sure the .htaccess there is gone.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably used a permanent redirect which has been cached by your browser, just clear the cache.

Comment: Yep, that explains it. +1 for thinking of the `permanent` that I forgot.